# Samsung USB SSD T5 not showing under /dev

Tags: usb, ssd, samsung

I'm trying to get a Samsung USB SSD T5 working with Ubuntu 18.04.  The device shows in dmesg (below), but does not get a device name (does not show in blkid or gparted).  It works when plugged into a mac or pc, so the device and cable are working, and other USB flash drives work fine on the ubuntu machine.

dmesg output (tried plug/unplug from USB3 and USB2 port):

```
[1731716.326424] usb 2-8: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[1731716.352388] usb 2-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61f5
[1731716.352393] usb 2-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[1731716.352396] usb 2-8: Product: Portable SSD T5
[1731716.352398] usb 2-8: Manufacturer: Samsung
[1731716.352401] usb 2-8: SerialNumber: 1234567B46E0
[1731716.385973] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[1731855.888004] usb 2-8: USB disconnect, device number 2
[1732337.609277] usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[1732337.762841] usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=61f5
[1732337.762846] usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[1732337.762849] usb 1-12: Product: Portable SSD T5
[1732337.762851] usb 1-12: Manufacturer: Samsung
[1732337.762853] usb 1-12: SerialNumber: 1234567B46E0
```

lsusb -v output:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04e8:61f5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04e8 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x61f5
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           2 Samsung
  iProduct                3 Portable SSD T5
  iSerial                 1 1234567B46E0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     98
      iInterface              0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-in pipe (0x03)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Data-out pipe (0x04)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Status pipe (0x02)
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
        Command pipe (0x01)
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           42
  bNumDeviceCaps          3
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x0000f41e
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat        2047 micro seconds
  ** UNRECOGNIZED:  14 10 0a 00 01 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 30 40 0a 00 b0 40 0a 00
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

How do I get the device to appear under /dev under ubuntu so I can format it?

Comment: Are you using a USB 3.1 port? Are you connecting an external power source? Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 19.04 USB flash drive, and see if the drive is seen then. Go to the Samsung website and download their `Samsung Magician` software and check that the SSD firmware is current.

Comment: @heynnema Tried USB3.0 and USB2.0 ports (no 3.1 port on that machine).   If I boot to clonezilla, it sees the drive as a device.  Also tried 19.04 on a USB 3.1 port on a different machine, and it also sees the drive as a device.

Comment: Please clarify. On a DIFFERENT machine, the drive works on 19.04 and a USB 3.1 port, yes? On the original machine, what happens with 19.04 and USB 2/3 ports. Also, please answer my other questions. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema: Yes, on a different machine the drive works on 19.04 on both USB 3.0 and 3.1 ports.  The Samsung Magician software recognizes the drive as a T5 but says it is unsupported by Samsung Magician, so no possibility of a FW upgrade with that. Rebooting the original machine to boot to 19.04 Ubuntu Live will be a bit tricky (the machine is a server with some critical things running), but I may be able try when there is a window.

Comment: @heynnema: Updated to 19.04, and still seeing the same issue.

Comment: In your BIOS, are USB ports set to legacy, or something else?

Comment: @heynnema.  USB ports are set to legacy.